# Italics not displaying properly (for me?)

Tags: bug

This came up in this answer: https://music.stackexchange.com/a/66324/2639  --

[image: Here's a screen grab]

the term "physical modeling" should be *italicized* (Todd put it inside *'s).  I've also italicized "italicized" in the previous sentence; I'm not seeing it.

I'm not seeing that the *italicized* words are visually distinct from the the rest of the response.

Maybe this has something to do with some particular aspect of my window/browser settings, but maybe not.

This is in CentOS 7.

This seems to be a feature of the fonts used on this site.  The fonts on several other SE sites are different, and do display italics (for me):

[image]

Comment: What's your OS and/or browser? I encounter that on an old Fedora 24 system using Firefox, but it's fine on my up-to-date Fedora machine.

Comment: @Richard  centos 7 — it is probably the same problem.  Btw I see the italics on my phone.

Comment: Is this the only SE with this issue? If not, it might be better to post on Meta SE.